# Default values with SnappyDB

Tags: java, android, snappydb

I'm using SnappyDB in my app as a store for some key value pairs.
I'm wrapping the DB interface with my own interface with default values in it's api. Example:

String get(String key, String defaultValue);

I noticed the only way to know if a key doesn't exist in the DB is to catch an exception and assume the reason for it was a missing key (which is a wild assumption).

Any ideas on how I could implement the default value feature in a less ugly, more accurate way that won't hide relevant exceptions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
boolean isKeyExist = snappyDB.exists("key");
```